# PIVOT in ORACLE 10G

Tags: oracle10g

I have following table in ORACLE 10G :-

### AUTOID  PLAN_DATE   ITEM_CODE   QTY

5               27-04-16               F10000010               10
7               27-04-16               F10000060               30
8               27-04-16               F10000020               10

**Require OutPut is :-**

Date
               F10000010               F10000060               F10000020
27-04-16               10                              30                              10

As we know there is no pivot function available in oracle 10g. So how can we do this. Here Item_CODE is dynamic code which can change according to date.
Any help will be highly appericable.

Thanks
PREM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using following procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select PLAN_DATE ';
    begin
        for x in (select distinct ITEM_CODE,qty from XXES_DAILY_PLAN_TRAN where PLAN_DATE='27-04-2016')
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
              ' , sum(case when qty = '''||x.qty||''' then qty else 0 end) as '||x.ITEM_CODE;
                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;
        sql_query := sql_query || ' from XXES_DAILY_PLAN_TRAN where PLAN_DATE=''27-04-2016'' group by PLAN_DATE ';
        dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        open p_cursor for sql_query;
end;

//calling

variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot(:x)
print x